# Extern Hard Drive (HD) is not detected by Ubuntu 18.04 perhaps because a error during reinstall Ubuntu with HD plugged

Tags: system-installation, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, external-hdd

A long time ago I used a External Hard Drive (HD) to install Ubuntu in a laptop. During the installation a error happened. I didn't use this HD until nowaday.

Now I have trying use this HD (there are important files inside that) and Ubuntu 18.04 have not detecting HD (I tryed using this HD with different laptops ). The HD is not listed when I use fdisk (`sudo fdisk -l`) or  lsblk (`lsblk`). However HD is listed when I use dmesg (`dmesg`), but is flaged with error -71.

My laptops are 2 Dell Vostro 1520 with Ubuntu 18.04 and HD is Dell too, model SRD00F1 (1TB).

I'm  a Ubuntu user and begginer user of Terminal.

Are there any thing I can do  to recovery HD or at least datas?

Thanks by helps!

Comment: Can you supply power to the USB enclosure, or maybe even use a Y splitter so two ports can supply power to the drive? Look at https://urukrama.wordpress.com/2009/01/27/usb-drive-not-recognised-error-71/ for one possible solution.

Comment: If it doesn't show in `sudo lshw -C disk, it's dead or problematically powered. Can you use a powered USB hub?

Comment: You said you used HDD to install Ubuntu. Did you use dd to write ISO to drive. That is intended for small drives as it erases drive. It actually totally erased first part of drive for size of ISO including partition table. Some data may still be on rest of drive, but difficult to get to.  See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery & 
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: After a long time and many tries, follow updates! Now, when I run `dmesg` I get a mensage: **Asking for cache data failed** related to this HDD.  Gparted didn't list the HDD. Testdisk list HDD and show information about size. However when I tried **Analisys** HDD I got the message **Partition: Read error**. Reading about dmesg results I found that HDD has a memory cache and perhaps the problem is related to it. Reading about Testdisk results I found that problems can be related to partition table. I didn't give up yet!  I'm gratefull for any help!